# Hibernate : Map single VO to two tables

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have two tables - `Table1` and `Table2`. Data structure of both the tables is same. 
I have single VO for both `Table1` and `Table2`. I have two `.hbm.xml` file for two tables separately - 
`Table1.hbm.xml` and `Table2.hbm.xml`

In my java code, based on a condition I either need to save to `Table1` or `Table2`

```
if(someCondition)
{
session.saveOrUpdate(VO); //This should be for Table1
}
else
{
session.saveOrUpdate(VO); //This should be for Table2
}
```

My problem is since that VO is same, there will be conflict in deciding which table to save.

Is it possible to have same VO mapped to two tables?

**Note**: The reason why I have such a requirement is Table1 and Table2 are in separate tablespace. One is partitioned and the other is not.
      There are couple of other reasons for such a weird requirement which is beyond my control to change the architecture now.

Comment: No. You have no inheritance at the database level so using a MapperSuperclass is what you need: 2 Entity classes which can inherit all common fields from this MappedSuperclass. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance#Mapped_Superclasses

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion using two entity managers is a bit too much. What you need is to have a good abstraction around the table.

You can map the same class as many times you want you just have to map it under different name.

Than one good Repository pattern working with the abstract entity (instead of the concrete one) combined with a Factory or Builder to generate the two objects will get the job done. If you follow this approach you will not need to have this IF-ELSE flow.

```
@MappedSuperClass
class AbstractMappedSomeTimes {
      private mappedAttribute;
}

@Table("yourtablename")
public class  MappedOnce extends AbstractEntity{

}

@Table("yourtablename")
public class  MappedTwise extends AbstractEntity{

}
```

Than you can have Repository working with AbstractMappedSomeTimes types of objects. You can also create a Factory that will generate either MappedOnce objects or MappedTwise objects.

Comment: If I create same class under different names, then there will be many places where I need to change my code. Eg., in getters and setters, I need to first check from which VO I need to retrieve and then create instance of that particular entity.

Comment: No you don't you will always work with the abstract class! Only on creation time you will use the Factory/Builder to construct the actual instance.